# GCP SQL 2016 Instance, I want to downgrade SQL to SQL Express

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently implemented a GCP VM Instance using the SQL-2016/windows 2019 image. after some usage, it's now come to my attention that the client only needs SQLExpress.
With this instance the SQL component is costing a large % of the monthly cost.

Q: is there a way to change the subscription without recreating a VM with a new image?

Nothing I have find in GCP documentation or related forums have come up with anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SOF! Please add more details regarding your research efforts and be specific on the issue if any.

Comment: AFAIK, no, you need to save your data, recreate a new instance and to restore the data.

Comment: You must backup, create a new instance and restore. SQL Server Express is intended for development and has real limitations such as 1 GB memory, 1 MB buffer cache. The buffer limitation will really affect performance. Make sure your client understands that the server will be much slower than a standard instance.